# Laravel hasOne + group_by, get sum

Tags: laravel

I'm currently scratching my head with this one.

**What I have.**

`$entries = Meta::whereIn('settlement_id', [1])->groupBy('client_id')->get();`

`Meta::model()` has a hasOne relation with other tables, in my example with a `Sport` table. With one attribute in my array I can achieve what I want.

So in a loop I have my field available `$entry->Sport->amount` this works perfectly.

**What I need.**

`$entries = Meta::whereIn('settlement_id', [1,2,3])->groupBy('client_id')->get();`

Now when I expand my array with multiple id's, I expect that `$entry->Sport->amount` returns the sum of all id's. But it doesn't.

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You say it expects it to return the sum all IDs, what *does* it return at the moment?

Comment: It returns the value of the first record it finds, not a sum of all fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your hasOne relation means that each **Meta** will have a separate **Sport**, so when you loop `$entries` each `$entry->Sport` will have the **amount** related to the current **Meta**, not a sum of all of them.

If you want to have the sum of **Sport** amount for specific **Meta**s it might be easier to make a query from the **Sport** model, something like this (I don't know how your relations is setup so this is just an example):

`Sport::whereIn('meta_id', [1,2,3])->sum('amount');`

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct, is there a way that I can achieve this? By changing hasOne to something else?

I don't want to query each specific related Meta table.

`public function Sport()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Sport', 'settlement_meta_id');
    }`

my database table Sport looks like this:

`protected $fillable = [
        'settlement_meta_id',
        'bet',
        'payout'
];`